# Shibboleth not appending any nameid to SAML response

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth

We are trying to do a single setup with Shibboleth Identity Provider 3 and 1 service.

We have configured the Shibboleth IDP3 to use the OpenLDAP service that we are running. This is working as authentication is succesful. (see green underlined part image). This is with a user we created in the LDAP who is named 'test'.

[image]

Now the problem is that the entire transaction fails because we seem to lack a nameid in our SAML response.

We have made multiple attempts to fix this, here are some of the changes we tried.

In attribute-resolver-ldap.xml we added:

```
<resolver:AttributeDefinition id="mail" xsi:type="ad:Simple" sourceAttributeID="mail">
    <resolver:Dependency ref="myLDAP" />
    <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="enc:SAML1String" name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:mail" encodeType="false" />
    <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="enc:SAML2String" name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" friendlyName="mail" encodeType="false" />
</resolver:AttributeDefinition>
```

In attribute-resolver.xml we added an attributedefinition and a dataconnector as follows:

```
<!--
   Attribute definition that expects to get the 'email' attribute from the ldap connector
   defined as its dependency and encode it as a SAML 2 name identifier.
-->
<resolver:AttributeDefinition xsi:type="Simple" xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:resolver:ad"
                              id="googleNameID"
                              sourceAttributeID="cn">

    <!--
       The data connector expected to provide the source attribute, email.  Note how the
       value of the 'ref' attribute is the identifier given to the LDAP data connector.
    -->
    <resolver:Dependency ref="ldap" />

    <!-- Encoder that transforms the attribute into a SAML2 NameID -->
    <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="SAML2StringNameID" xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:attribute:encoder"
                               nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" />

</resolver:AttributeDefinition>
```

dataconnector (the <..> values are filled in correctly):

```
<!-- An LDAP connector that pulls in, at least, an attribute called email. -->
<resolver:DataConnector xsi:type="LDAPDirectory" xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:resolver:dc"
                        id="ldap"
                        ldapURL="ldap://localhost:389"
                        baseDN="dc=<FIRSTDC>,dc=<SECONDDC>"
                        principal="cn=admin,dc=<FIRSTDC>,dc=<SECONDDC>"
                        principalCredential="<PASS>">

    <FilterTemplate>
        <![CDATA[
            (cn=test)
        ]]>
    </FilterTemplate>
</resolver:DataConnector>
```

In the saml-nameid.xml file we added a nameIDgenerator (we did this for both SAML1 and 2):

```
<bean parent="shibboleth.SAML2AttributeSourcedGenerator"
            p:format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
            p:attributeSourceIds="#{ {'mail'} }" />
```

In our ldap.properties file we assume we have configured everything correctly as the authentication itself works fine.

The error at the service side is that it can't process the SAML message:

```
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: NameID element must be present as part of the Subject in the Response message, please enable it in the IDP configuration
```

Answer (score 3):

There could be many reason for this. There are some issues I could see in the configuration you have provided:

1. In **attribute-resolver.xml**, you have defined AttributeDefinition ID as `id="googleNameID"` while AttributeSourceIDs in **saml-nameid.xml** is set as `p:attributeSourceIds="#{ {'mail'} }"`. These IDs should be exactly same. Change your AttributeDefinition in attribute-resolver.xml to:

   ```
   <resolver:AttributeDefinition xsi:type="Simple" xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:resolver:ad"
                             id="mail" sourceAttributeID="cn">
       <resolver:Dependency ref="ldap" />
       <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="enc:SAML2String" name="mail" friendlyName="mail"/>
   </resolver:AttributeDefinition>
   ```
2. In **conf/saml-nameid.properties**, uncomment and set default NameID as EmailAddress like this:

   ```
   idp.nameid.saml2.default = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
   ```
3. You have not defined any Attribute Filter Policy. Add the following to the  **conf/attribute-filter.xml**:

   ```
   <afp:AttributeFilterPolicy id="ldapAttributes">
       <afp:PolicyRequirementRule xsi:type="basic:ANY" />
       <afp:AttributeRule attributeID="mail">
            <afp:PermitValueRule xsi:type="basic:ANY"/>
       </afp:AttributeRule>
   </afp:AttributeFilterPolicy>
   ```